# Meteor query runs perfectly fine on server but not on client

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-collections

So I have a simple server file:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

const Animals = new Mongo.Collection("animals");

let animalsFindOne = Targets.findOne({animal: "henry"});
console.log(_.get(animalsFindOne, 'food.favorite.amount'));
```

And a `animals.js` file that renders to the template

```
import {Template} from "meteor/templating";
import {Mongo} from "meteor/mongo";

import "/imports/ui/targets/animals.html";

const Animals = new Mongo.Collection("animals");
let animalsFindOne = Targets.findOne({animal: "henry"});

Template.targets.helpers({
    foodAmount: function() {
        return _.get(animalsFindOne, 'food.favorite.amount';
    }
});
```

I could return *"foo"* as foodAmount and the template would render it perfectly fine. For `_.get` I use `erasaur:meteor-lodash`, which works perfectly fine in `server.js`. In the server console the output is "5", the output that is expected and great.
What piece am I missing here?
**Edit**: Also I have autopublish installed, and I am not looking forward to removing it, as this software is a test anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `animalsFindOne` is already defined outside the `foodAmount` helper, thus it won't trigger the Template's reactivity-based redrawing mechanism.

In order to gain reactivity in helpers you need to call queries within the helper:

```js
import {Template} from "meteor/templating";
import {Mongo} from "meteor/mongo";

import "/imports/ui/targets/animals.html";

const Animals = new Mongo.Collection("animals");


Template.targets.helpers({
    foodAmount: function() {
        let animalsFindOne = Targets.findOne({animal: "henry"});
        return _.get(animalsFindOne, 'food.favorite.amount';
    }
});
```

edit: Meteor allows [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with the more recent versions, so no need for lodash here:

```js
Template.targets.helpers({
    foodAmount: function() {
        let animalsFindOne = Targets.findOne({animal: "henry"});
        return animalsFindOne?.food?.favorite?.amount
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, I need to read up more on meteors reactivity I guess. But thank you so much! Also nice suggestion with meteors optional chaining. I could not find that feature and then instead used lodash :D Thanks!